# How to write a function that takes a Python bytearray as argument and computes the proportion

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am new in python and struggling to write a function that takes a Python bytearray as an argument and computes the proportion of ones in it.

So far I have tried below-mentioned code:

```
def cal_bit_proportion(test):
   test = bytearray( 2 )
   test[ 0 ] = 0b00000000
   test[ 1 ] = 0b00000001
    # bp = (need to calculate the proportion)
    return bp     # bp means bit proportion
```

It would be really great if someone helps me to solve it by using python 3.4+, or redirect me to appropriate source from where I can learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
sum(bin(x).count('1') for x in test)
```

That is, convert each byte in the bytearray to its binary string representation, and count the ones, then sum all of those counts.

Then you can divide by the total number of bits: `8 * len(test)`.

Comment: @ John Zwinck, Thanks for the quick reply. I have modified my code as per above-mentioned suggestion. Still unable to find the actual requirements. I have modified my code for further assistance. If possible then, please help me to solve it.

Comment: @M.liza: It is not fair to edit your question which I already answered into a totally different question.  I have restored your original question now.  I suggest you post a new question regarding your new issues, and consider accepting this answer if it addresses the question you posted.

Comment: @ John Zwinck, Thanks for your suggestion. I will post another question. I was not aware of it. Sorry for the editing. And your answer helped me to understand the way to call a function regarding bytearray.